# Intents to call gpx app

Tags: android, gpx

My `Android` app is a tool to help mappers draw Orienteering´s map. Instead of using a `GPS` device and a booklet he/she uses a cell phone to record those IOF elements and save then on `.gpx` format that can be read by a CAD software that draw the map.

It has no graphic interface on it. My idea is to use one app already available that plot tracks from a `gpx` file. I made some test with two that very good: GPXViewer and Locus Map.

When I trigger the intents below both reacts same way saying there is a issue with the file I am asking to show, the "TestGPX.gpx" that is saved on Documents directory of the cell phone. On both cases, the app I call opens but complain, being Locus a bit more specific: "Invalid value: content://com.hbcavalcanti.com.isomspinner1.fileprovider/Documments/TestGPX.gpx".

Since they are open, if I manually choose the file both plot it without any issue. I suspect is not by chance both complains, i.e. I should be doing something not right:

```
    public void viewGPXVButton(View view){
    // Get directory Documents
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    // Form fileprovider
    String fileProvider = getPackageName()+".fileprovider";
    // Get complete file name. Use a fixed filename "TestGPX.gpx" just to make shure
    File file = new File(root , "TestGPX.gpx");
    // Get file URI
    try{
        Uri attachment = getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), fileProvider, file);
        // Send it
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(attachment,"application/gpx");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        // Check the app is pressent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
            // Yes
            startActivity(intent);
        }else {
            // No
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  "GPX viewer not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }
    // Fail to call
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Fail to open GPX viewer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
    finish();
}
```

This is what Debug says:

```
root:"/storage/emulated/0/Documents"
fileProvider:"com.hbcavalcanti.isomspinner1.fileprovider"
file:"/storage/emulated/0/Documents/TestGPX.gpx"
attachment:"content://com.hbcavalcanti.isomspinner1.fileprovider/Documents/TestGPX.gpx"
```

This is part of my Manifest:

```
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.hbcavalcanti.isomspinner1.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `content://com.hbcavalcanti.com.isomspinner1.fileprovider/Documments/TestGPX.gpx` Try to open an InputStream for that content scheme yourself. Its possible that the apps you choose are not able to read from a content scheme and instead expect a file path. Which apps are you talking about? Also show the "@xml/filepaths" file.

Comment: `content://com.hbcavalcanti.com.isomspinner1.fileprovider/Documments/TestGPX.gpx` That looks like an impossible content scheme. But we can only tell when you post that xml file.

Comment: Did you consider what I said about debug?
Anyway, this is xml/filepath:
<path xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="Documents" path="Documents/"/>

</path>

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`. setFlags() will erase the flags you tried to set with addFlags(). You could reverse the statements.

Comment: Hey greenapp, you got it!
When I reversed the statements it worked.

I tried both apps GPXViewer and Locus Map and they worked just fine, no complains.
To be honest, I guess your first guess about they cannot handle a content uri but a file path was the way. After some SO research and crashes I did what you suggested and it fixed the issue.

Case closed!

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot: is never too much say "Thanks!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locus Map application has also its own public API that 3rd party developers may use.
Check [this API class](https://github.com/asamm/locus-api/blob/master/locus-api-android/src/main/java/locus/api/android/ActionDisplayTracks.java) that allows sending tracks directly into the application without the need to use any GPX file in the middle. With this, you may simply display your track real-time on the Locus Map map while your app may do its work on the background.

I'm not sure if this is use-case you want to achieve, or if points were really "only" to display GPX track on the mobile phone. If second is correct, maybe even more useful may be export track into KML file, which is also supported by Google Earth and maybe (not sure) also directly by Google Maps app.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/k3b/LocationMapViewer/ is also capable to read gpx files in [gpx1.0 and gpx1.1 format](https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/data#gpx).

Since it is open source you can debug what happens. you have to add "content: gpx" uris to manifest for your usecase to make it work for non-file uri-s.

`de.k3b.android.LocationMapViewer#loadGeoPointDtosFromFile()` arlready uses `contentResolver.openInputStream()`.

Other usefull tools that might help:

- https://github.com/k3b/intent-intercept/ to analyse/manually send intent-s: open you app send gpx to intentintercept, edit the intent (i.e. change content:-uri to file: uri or change mime type and re-send modified intent.
- https://github.com/MajeurAndroid/Android-Applications-Info to look into the manifest-sourcecode of  GPXViewer and Locus-Map to see what kind of uri they can process.

All discussed android apps are available for free on [f-droid app store](http://f-droid.org/)

Comment: I will check and come back.